# Jquery Event won't fire after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

This is a rather strange issue with jquery. I am loading a div

```
<div id="container">
```

on page load. Each record is tabular data with a 'delete' ajax function associated with it. When the page loads and clicking the 'delete' link, the ajax call fires off just fine. 
However, once the event is fired, the data is returned from the ajax call, and the div is populated with data (but the page does not refresh or reload) 
When I click the link again, the ajax script will not fire. 
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.done").button({
    }).click(function() {
        var BatchID = $("input#BatchID").val();
        var Amount = $("input#Amount").val();
        var Name = $("input#CheckName").val();
        var Check_Number = $("input#Check_Number").val();
        var Company = $("select#Company").val();
        var Department = $("select#Department").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/app/usagCheckEntryWS.html',
            data: {
                "BatchID" : BatchID,
                "Amount" : Amount,
                "Name" : Name,
                "Check_Number" : Check_Number,
                "Company" : Company,
                "Department" : Department
            },
            success: function (data) {
                    var ang = '';
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(obj, function() {
                       ang += '<table><tr><td width="45">' + this["RefID"] + '</td><td width="140">' + this["Name"] + '</td><td width="95">' + this["CheckNumber"] + '</td><td align="right" width="70">$' + this["Amount"] + '</td><td width="220" style="padding-left: 15px;">' + this["Description"] + '</td><td><div class="delete" rel="' + this["RefID"] + '"><span>Delete</span></div></td></tr></table>';
                    });
                    $('#container').html(ang);
                    $("input#Amount").val('');
                    $("input#CheckName").val('');
                    $("input#Check_Number").val('');
                    $("select#Company").val('MMS');
                    $("th#dept").hide();
                    $('input#CheckName').focus();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: does a console say anything?

Comment: Are you removing the delete link with the rest of the data and then re-appending it?

Comment: no chrome dev tools, doesnt show any event firing.

Comment: I don't see where you are binding the delete handler.

Comment: Also see excellent answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18144022

Answer (score 201, accepted):

When you remove an element and then replace it (via javascript), it loses any event bindings that were added to it on page load.

(This also applies to content added to the page after page load - i.e. ajax loaded content)

There are several possible solutions for this.

1) Encapsulate your "binding" code and call it both on page load and immediately after the element in question gets added back to the page. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // bind event handlers when the page loads.
    bindButtonClick();
});

function bindButtonClick(){
    $('.myClickableElement').click(function(){
        ... event handler code ...
    });
}

function updateContent(){
    $.ajax({
        url : '/ajax-endpoint.php',
        data : {'onMyWay' : 'toServer'},
        dataType : 'html',
        type : 'post',
        success : function(responseHtml){
            // .myClickableElement is replaced with new (unbound) html element(s)
            $('#container').html(responseHtml);

            // re-bind event handlers to '.myClickableElement'
            bindButtonClick();  
        }
    });
}
```

2) **The more elegant way to handle this**: use [jQuery's .on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). With it, you are able to bind event handlers to elements other than the event target - i.e. an element that never gets removed from the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.myClickableElement',function(){
        ... event handler code ....
    });
});
```

**Some further explanation:**

The `.on()` method uses ***[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)*** to tell a parent element to retain your event handler code (3rd argument), and fire it when the event target (2nd argument) has a certain type of event (1st argument) performed on it.

If you are using a version of jQuery prior to 1.7 use the now deprecated [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method which essentially does the same thing.

Also, it is worth noting that because of the way events "bubble up" through the dom tree, the event target (2nd argument of .on() method) must be a descendant of the delegating element (jQuery object's selector). For example, **the following would NOT work**

```
<div id="container-1">
    <div>
        <div id="another-div">
            Some Stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container-2">
    <a id="click-me">Event Target!!!</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#container-1').on('click','#click-me',function(){
        ... event handler code ....
        // This will never execute, should've used '#container-2', or 'body', or 'document' instead of '#container-1'
    });
</script>
```

The `body` or `document` elements are usually safe choices since typically every element on the page is a descendant.

Comment: You - are - The - Man! 
I met this issue when replacing parts of the dom using socket.io events, My bootstrap carousel would not trigger events I need when slides finished scrolling, I have wrapped my event driven js in the bindsomething() functions as you described and it's all running fine now, Thank you!

Comment: Wow. Excellent solution. I have had a problem with SoundCloud auto play in Chrome, due to Google's new Auto Play policy. This manages to fix the problem. I have added a flag, so that when the window loads, the bindButtonClick function is passed 0, so the event handler is prevented from being executed. But, inside the Ajax call, I pass it 1, and the event handler kicks in!

Comment: Just a question and a comment, although I see that this is an old post.  I have had a lot of trouble using function submitorderhandler() {

$(document).on('click', '#xxx",  function(e) {

Comment: where's the option to buy a virtual beer in this thing?

Comment: I've heard that having lots of document or body level event handlers can slow down a page.

Comment: @Jess can't say I've ever noticed that, doesn't mean it isn't true. I will say that this answer is really old now and while it may still be relevant to those using this approach, I would recommend folks to take a modern approach (using component-driven frameworks or libraries) for any client-side apps with any sort of complexity involved. Usually those frameworks are not using jQuery at all for event binding

Comment: Thank you for this brief explanation especially 2nd point, until now i thought i knew `.on()` and how it functions lol

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the event script in DIV and run a Replaceall command after dynamically loading the content.

```
<div class="somescript">
-- Event Script that you want to map with dnamically added content
<div>
```

-- Dynamically load your content and run the below command after it.

```
$(".somescript").replaceAll($(".somescript"));
```

Once the dynamically loaded content is loaded and replace command has been run, the events will be mapped and code will run fine.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that other can learn from it. What makes you think that any handlers bound to elements within that `div` are still bound after replacing the content?