# I cannot do any jQuery on an Anchor Class within a popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I have a link within a popup box, that has a class. When I attach a function to this link (with .click() or others) nothing happens.

I have the following code (sorry there's a quite a bit of it, but I wanted to be thorough to get the potential answer)...

```
    $(".comment-lkes").hover(function(e){
    var HTMLbuild = "";
    var userNameURL = "/user.php?u=";
    var commentID = parseInt($(this).parents("li").attr("data-commentid"),10);

    //fire off AJAX with the comment_ID to get the usernames of the likes
    $.ajax({
        url: "AJAX_commentlikes_JSON.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            cid: commentID
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        var HTMLbuild = "";
        HTMLbuild += '<ul class="userNameList">\n';

        $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
            var username = value.user_name;
            HTMLbuild += '<li>';
            HTMLbuild += '<a href="' + userNameURL + username + '" target="_blank" class="popupuser">' + username + '</a></br>'; 
            HTMLbuild += "</li>\n";
        });

        HTMLbuild += '</ul>';
        $("#pop-up").html(HTMLbuild);

        $('div#pop-up').show()
    });
}, function () {
    if (moveFlag === false) {
        $('div#pop-up').hide();
    }
});

$('.comment-lkes').mousemove(function (e) {
    if (moveFlag === false) {
        $("div#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    }
});

$('.comment-lkes').click(function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (moveFlag === false) {
        moveFlag = true;
        $("div#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    } else {
        moveFlag = false;
        $("div#pop-up").hide();
    }
});

$('.popupuser').click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

So, the popup box successfully displays, the CSS is below

```
#pop-up {
  z-index: 99999;  
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

The AJAX successfully generates the HTML, the popup box successfully displays all the usernames, and when the link is clicked, it takes the user to a new tab to the correct page.
However, none of the jQuery for `$('.popupuser').click(function () {` does anything. As in, the `alert` does not display and the link goes through.

I have tried various methods to fix this, I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. Any help would be thoroughly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to another post, and the clue given by WisdmLabs, I got there, I'll explain my process.

If I copied the jQuery into the console, it worked.
So I figured it must be something to do with the .class not existing when the page is loaded, as jQuery creates some code and then plonks it into the DOM.

[Jquery Event won't fire after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767919/jquery-event-wont-fire-after-ajax-call)

The above link sorted it for me, so now my code is...

```
$('body').on('click','.popupuser',function(){
    alert("clicked popupuser");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with the response of AJAX, use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method -

```
$('.popupuser').live('click', function () {});
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me this function, however, this still doesn't solve the problem I am afraid.

As I understand it, everything is drawn up, it will only write the HTML to the popup once the AJAX is `.done()` ?

I have a gut feeling that it's because it;s within so many DIVs and other classes, or because it's within something with CSS with such a high `z-index` that this is causing the issues. Alas, I am guessing and tearing hair out still.

Comment: also, changing it to .on() does nothing as .live() is now deprecated