# Issue with JQuery libs no longer firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did have this working, but I have changed things about to make things neater and it no longer works.  I have removed some code, but I have a page project.php which has the basic structure like so

```
<?php include_once "templates/header.php"; ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Activity</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="projectActionSelect">
                            <option value="">Please select...</option>
                            <option value="addProject">Add Project</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" id="projectMainContainer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php include_once "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

header.php and footer.php basically does what you would expect them to do e.g. add my scripts.

I then have a javascript file which handles things.  I thing it does is

```
$('#projectActionSelect').on('change', function (e) {
    if($(this).val() == 'addProject'){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'templates/project/addProject.php'
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#projectMainContainer').append(data);
        });
    } else {
        $('#addProjectForm').remove();
    }
});
```

So if the select is changed to Add Project, it attaches addProject.php which is basically a template containing a form.  I wont show it all, but it looks like the following

```
<div id="addProjectForm">
    <h2 class="main-header">Add Project</h2>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="projectIdentified">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-5 noPadding listLayout">
                <label for="startDate" class="col-sm-12 control-label green marginBottom10">WHEN</label>
                <ul>
                    <li>1. Does it start?</li>
                    <li>2. Does it have to be delivered?</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div id="false-height"></div>
                <p><span class="fixed-width">Start Date:</span> <input type="text" id="startDate"></p>
                <p><span class="fixed-width">Delivery Date:</span> <input type="text" id="deliveryDate"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="sbtBtnIdentified">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

So this all works fine, if I change the select the form is added to the page.

This is where it gets strange. In the form thats added which I show above, there are two date fields.  In my javascript file I have

```
$( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if (date) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate());
        }
        $("#deliveryDate").datepicker("option","minDate", date);
    }
});

$( "#deliveryDate" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if (date) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate());
        }
        $("#startDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", date || 0);
    }
});
```

But when I select the field nothing happens.

I also have a validation method but if I click submit, no validation occurs and the page refreshes.

I can see my libraries are loaded so this does not seem to be the problem.

The important thing to note is that this was all working fine the way I had it before, and this was done through hiding a showing the form.  This has only stopped working since I decided to load the form using ajax instead.

Is there any reason why this would cause it to break?  If there is a reason, would be good to get an explanation so I can understand it fully.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the `<script>` tags that add in jQuery were removed, so there is no jQuery.

Comment: Ajax is async (by default), this could be the reason... Your question is missing some context, especially how you are loading content using ajax but i guess you are trying to initialize plugin before elements are in the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your javascript code runs your input fields can't be found.

Be sure to bind the controls after they are added on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to actually find the answer after thllbrg posted his

[Jquery Event won't fire after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767919/jquery-event-wont-fire-after-ajax-call)