# jQuery event won't work after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an expand/collapse block for which I have written a function as such:

```
function expandCollapse() {
    var $btnShowHide = $('.btn-show-hide');
    var $contentShowHide = $('.content-show-hide');

    contentToggle();

    $btnShowHide.each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            var i = $btnShowHide.index(this);
            $contentShowHide.eq(i).slideToggle('fast');
            $contentShowHide.eq(i).toggleClass('collapsed');

            if ($contentShowHide.eq(i).hasClass('collapsed')) {
                $('.icon-show-hide', this).text('+');
            } else {
                $('.icon-show-hide', this).text('-');
            }
        });
    });

    function contentToggle() {
        $contentShowHide.each(function() {
            var i = $contentShowHide.index(this);
            if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
                $(this).hide();
                $('.icon-show-hide', $btnShowHide.eq(i)).text('+');
            } else {
                $('.icon-show-hide', $btnShowHide.eq(i)).text('-');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and I call this function on `$(document).ready`. This works fine but fails when there is an ajax call done in the page. So, I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13767985/1456913) and called the function again on ajax success, but this makes the behaviour odd (like, clicking on the btn once will collapse and expand the content multiple times for a single click). Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Sample HTML (there could be multiple of these on one page):

```
<h3 class="btn-show-hide">
 <span class="icon-show-hide"></span>
 <span>Title</span>
</h3>
<div class="content-show-hide collapsed">
//Stuff
</div>
```

Comment: When and how are you calling expandCollapse()? And can you post the HTML too ;)

Comment: @AdamJeffers on document.ready and ajax success.

Comment: Ok, can you also post the code where you are using ajax

Comment: The ajax calls are being made through JSF. I just have a function ajaxSuccess that is being called when the JSF is done.

Comment: See my answer, each time you call `expandCollapse` you are rebinding the same event handler to all your buttons over and over. If you really don't want to change your code structure you COULD make a call to `off()` beforehand....

Comment: If your button triggers are replaced as part of the AJAX response content, then you will need to bind the click events to a static parent and use a [delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements?lq=1).

Comment: Is there a reason why you're binding your event handlers in a loop? That's considered bad form. Consider using @Jasen's suggestion of using delegation.

Comment: @Jasen so, I could do $('body').on() ?

Comment: Yes, you can bind to body but it would be better to find the closest static parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution is to set an `off` before listening to the event.
So, it would just be

```
 $btnShowHide.each(function() {
        $(this).off('click').on('click', function() {
            var i = $btnShowHide.index(this);
            $contentShowHide.eq(i).slideToggle('fast');
            $contentShowHide.eq(i).toggleClass('collapsed');

            if ($contentShowHide.eq(i).hasClass('collapsed')) {
                $('.icon-show-hide', this).text('+');
            } else {
                $('.icon-show-hide', this).text('-');
            }
        });
    });
```

This fixed my problem but I have no idea why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are removing/replacing all instances of `$('.btn-show-hide');` and `$('.content-show-hide');` before each call to `expandCollapse()` you are re-adding the same event handler over and over, which I suspect is the cause of the multiple collapse/expands.

```
$btnShowHide.each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            var i = $btnShowHide.index(this);
            $contentShowHide.eq(i).slideToggle('fast');
            $contentShowHide.eq(i).toggleClass('collapsed');

            if ($contentShowHide.eq(i).hasClass('collapsed')) {
                $('.icon-show-hide', this).text('+');
            } else {
                $('.icon-show-hide', this).text('-');
            }
        });
    });
```

The above code adds a new event handler each time you call `expandCollapse()`, perhaps it should be placed outside this function and only executed once...

Comment: I just tried this. I moved the code you highlighted to document.ready and just called contentToggle(); in ajaxSuccess() and document.ready. The click event no longer works.

Comment: @A.O. Your answer/example code is exactly the same as what OP already has?

Comment: Did you also move your references to `$btnShowHide` and `$contentShowHide`? @AdamJeffers The code snippet is the same, I'm saying that it should be moved outside of the `expandCollapse()` function so that he isn't rebinding his click event handlers with each call to `expandCollapse()`

Comment: @A.O. I believe the below restructuring of the code by AdamJeffers is what you are referring to. I tried it and the click events fail again.