# Cacheing the DOM and binding click events on elements that are not rendered yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching, template-engine

> "Stable application development requires strict organizing of code
>   into clear 'blocks'."

To that end I am using Mustache to render data from my scripts into my HTML.

I am storing my Mustache templates in special script tags:

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    Mustache template goes here and is invisible
</script>
```

To render the template in a `div` I simply call the Mustache render function

```
var template = $('#template').html();
$('#someDiv').html(Mustache.render(template));
```

Now imagine I want to bind a click event to an element in a Mustache template or Cache the elements that I will use later... I obviously can't do that on page load because the template is not rendered yet.

To get the event to work I have to declare an event only *after* I have rendered the HTML. To use an element I have to manually select it when I need it e.g. `$('.foo')` instead of the cached `this.foo`

The consequence is that now I have on('click) events and jQuery selections strewn throughout my object and not in the bindEvents and cacheDOM functions.

Here is a fiddle with a simplified example of the problem:  https://jsfiddle.net/6L2ry6hr/

In the above example it is not to bad... but as my apps get more complex it is becoming a bit of a hassle.

Comment: The link is incomplete

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` at Question? What are you trying to achieve? What is purpose of IIFE and `foo` object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Event wont fire after ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767919/jquery-event-wont-fire-after-ajax-call)

Comment: @guest see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6L2ry6hr/

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst Yes, not certain what issue is?

Answer (score 1):

> Now imagine I want to bind a click event to an element in a Mustache
>   template
>
> I obviously can't do that on page load because the template is not rendered yet.

The requirement is possible using jQuery. The `.innerHTML` of a `<script>` element can be passed to `jQuery()` with an event and event handler attached.

```
jQuery.holdReady(true);
var template = jQuery($("#template").html());
// template.filter("element").on("event", function() {// do stuff})
jQuery("body").append(template);
jQuery.holdReady(false);
jQuery(function() {
  // do stuff
})
```