# Why does tooltip inside Timeline stop working after range change (Primefaces)?

Tags: primefaces, tooltip, jsf-2.2, timeline

I create Primefaces timeline with many events. After move mouse on event display, show a toolpit with information about this event (car number). Everything works after show first time, whem timeline rage change it stops working. I do not know why?

Update components from bean.
Update components with ajax update

```
<p:timeline id="timeline" value="#{schedulerControler.model}" var="event" varGroup="group" editable="true">
         <h:panelGroup id="myEvent" class="evenClassId#{event.id}">
            <h:outputText value="#{event.transportAsset.city}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <p:ajax event="rangechanged" update="tooltipsPanel" listener="{schedulerControler.rangeChanged}"/>
</p:timeline>

<p:panel id="tooltipsPanel" >
      <ui:repeat value="#{schedulerControler.model.events}" var="varTooltip" >
                    <p:tooltip for="@(.evenClassId#{varTooltip.data.id})">
                        <h:outputText value="#{varTooltip.data.carNumber}"/>
                    </p:tooltip>
      </ui:repeat>
</p:panel>
```

No error messages.

Comment: Pf version? And how does the ajax response look like? Did you analyze it?

Comment: Pf version is 7.0. I chec Ajax response but did not found solution, ststus 200 no errors.

Comment: update id="menuForm:tabs:tooltipsPanel"><div id="menuForm:tabs:tooltipsPanel" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-widget="widget_menuForm_tabs_tooltipsPanel"><div id="menuForm:tabs:tooltipsPanel_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content"><div id="menuForm:tabs:j_idt119:0:j_idt218" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-tooltip-right"><div class="ui-tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="ui-tooltip-text ui-shadow ui-corner-all">DDZ0XHC</div></div><script id="menuForm:tabs:j_idt119:0:j_idt218_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw;

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is similar to this reported issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4770

The key is in this post: [Jquery Event won't fire after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767919/jquery-event-wont-fire-after-ajax-call)

You need to bind your tooltip to the @body element until this can be fixed by PrimeFaces.